# For loop over elements in list

Tags: pandas, for-loop

This is my list:

```
letters = ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

I would like to make a for loop in my dataframe over the elements in my list and then winsorize the rows in my dataframe with the same index, so I tried:

```
index_a = df.index.tolist()
index_a = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(index_a))

for l in letters:
    for j in index_a:
          df[l].loc[j] = winsorize(df[l].loc[j], limits=[0.01, 0.01])
```

But I get the error: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: Somewhere above you have code that does something like `list = []`.  Now `list` is not the builtin function, rather it's an actual list.  What you are doing is equivalent to `[1, 2]()`.

Comment: How can I improve it?

Comment: Don't name a list `list`.

Comment: I didn't name it list.. I named it letters

Comment: Note that from Python 3.6 forward, dictionaries retain the order of key insertion.  You can change `list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(index_unique))` to `list(dict.fromkeys(index_unique))`.

Comment: I'm assuming that the error `'list' object is not callable` is pointing to the line `index_unique = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(index_unique))`.  If so, you have assigned a list to the built-in name `list` somewhere in your code.  If changing that line to `index_unique = [*dict.fromkeys(index_unique)]` solves your issue, that would be further proof that a list was assigned to the name `list`.

Comment: It does not solve the issue

Comment: Add the full traceback for the error `'list' object is not callable` to your question.

Comment: Check out [ask] for tips like how to write a good title.

Comment: If Steven's right, this is a duplicate of [Why does "example = list(...)" result in "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable"?](/q/31087111/4518341)